# Why asm for std::rotate is so bloated in comparison with "manual" version?

Tags: c++, optimization

So there was a debate about writing cleaner and more understandable (for another human) code, than trying to make the code more assembly-friendly.
I am in favor of writing understandable code with distinct actions, separate responsibilies, conform to C++ Guidelines, etc. So, in general, one should firstly take care of algorithmic complexity and write code for an *abstract machine*. Compilers are sophisticated enough to make neat optimisations.

So I have on one side a piece of code which I don't find clean or easy to understand from a glance (from Stroustroup's book, afaic):

```
void Window::move_to_top(Shape& s)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < shapes.size(); ++i)
        if (&s == shapes[i]) {
            for (++i; i < shapes.size(); ++i)
                shapes[i - 1] = shapes[i];
            shapes[shapes.size() - 1] = &s;
            return;
        }
}
```

And another version, which I consider more self-explanatory and easier to understand, using stanard library algorithms.

```
void Window::move_to_top(Shape& s)
{
    auto iterShape = std::find(shapes.begin(), shapes.end(), &s);
    std::rotate(iterShape, std::next(iterShape), shapes.end());
}
```

Both versions have linear complexity and basically do the same (both assume that `Shape &s` is stored within the array). **However**, with gcc `-O3`:
"Manual" version:

```
Window::move_to_top(Shape&):
        mov     r8, QWORD PTR [rdi+8]
        mov     rcx, QWORD PTR [rdi]
        mov     rdi, r8
        sub     rdi, rcx
        sar     rdi, 3
        je      .L1
        mov     eax, 1
        jmp     .L7
.L3:
        lea     rdx, [rax+1]
        cmp     rdi, rax
        je      .L1
        mov     rax, rdx
.L7:
        mov     edx, eax
        cmp     QWORD PTR [rcx-8+rax*8], rsi
        jne     .L3
        add     edx, 1
        movsx   rdx, edx
        cmp     rdi, rax
        jbe     .L6
.L5:
        mov     rax, QWORD PTR [rcx+rax*8]
        mov     QWORD PTR [rcx-16+rdx*8], rax
        mov     rax, rdx
        add     rdx, 1
        cmp     rdi, rax
        ja      .L5
.L6:
        mov     QWORD PTR [r8-8], rsi
        ret
.L1:
        ret
```

STL version:

```
Window::move_to_top(Shape&):
        push    r12
        push    rbp
        push    rbx
        mov     rax, QWORD PTR [rdi+8]
        mov     rbp, QWORD PTR [rdi]
        mov     rdx, rax
        sub     rdx, rbp
        mov     rcx, rdx
        sar     rdx, 5
        sar     rcx, 3
        test    rdx, rdx
        jle     .L2
        sal     rdx, 5
        add     rdx, rbp
        jmp     .L7
.L76:
        cmp     rsi, QWORD PTR [rbp+8]
        je      .L72
        cmp     rsi, QWORD PTR [rbp+16]
        je      .L73
        cmp     rsi, QWORD PTR [rbp+24]
        je      .L74
        add     rbp, 32
        cmp     rbp, rdx
        je      .L75
.L7:
        cmp     rsi, QWORD PTR [rbp+0]
        jne     .L76
.L3:
        lea     rdx, [rbp+8]
        cmp     rax, rdx
        je      .L1
        sub     rax, rbp
        cmp     rax, 16
        je      .L14
.L35:
        sar     rax, 3
        mov     esi, 1
.L15:
        mov     rdi, rax
        sub     rdi, rsi
        cmp     rsi, rdi
        jge     .L16
.L78:
        cmp     rsi, 1
        je      .L77
        lea     rcx, [0+rsi*8]
        lea     rdx, [rbp+0+rcx]
        test    rdi, rdi
        jle     .L19
        lea     r8, [rbp+16]
        cmp     rdx, r8
        setnb   r8b
        add     rcx, 16
        test    rcx, rcx
        setle   cl
        or      r8b, cl
        je      .L36
        lea     rcx, [rdi-1]
        cmp     rcx, 1
        jbe     .L36
        mov     r9, rdi
        xor     ecx, ecx
        xor     r8d, r8d
        shr     r9
.L21:
        movdqu  xmm0, XMMWORD PTR [rbp+0+rcx]
        movdqu  xmm1, XMMWORD PTR [rdx+rcx]
        add     r8, 1
        movups  XMMWORD PTR [rbp+0+rcx], xmm1
        movups  XMMWORD PTR [rdx+rcx], xmm0
        add     rcx, 16
        cmp     r9, r8
        jne     .L21
        mov     r9, rdi
        and     r9, -2
        lea     rcx, [0+r9*8]
        lea     r8, [rbp+0+rcx]
        add     rdx, rcx
        cmp     rdi, r9
        je      .L24
        mov     rcx, QWORD PTR [r8]
        mov     r9, QWORD PTR [rdx]
        mov     QWORD PTR [r8], r9
        mov     QWORD PTR [rdx], rcx
.L24:
        lea     rbp, [rbp+0+rdi*8]
.L19:
        cqo
        idiv    rsi
        test    rdx, rdx
        je      .L1
        mov     rax, rsi
        sub     rsi, rdx
        mov     rdi, rax
        sub     rdi, rsi
        cmp     rsi, rdi
        jl      .L78
.L16:
        lea     rdx, [0+rax*8]
        lea     r11, [rbp+0+rdx]
        cmp     rdi, 1
        je      .L79
        lea     rcx, [0+rdi*8]
        mov     r10, r11
        sub     r10, rcx
        test    rsi, rsi
        jle     .L37
        mov     rbx, rdx
        lea     r8, [rdx-16]
        sub     rbx, rcx
        cmp     rbx, r8
        lea     r9, [rbx-16]
        setle   cl
        cmp     rdx, r9
        setle   dl
        or      cl, dl
        je      .L38
        lea     rdx, [rsi-1]
        cmp     rdx, 1
        jbe     .L38
        mov     rbx, rsi
        add     r9, rbp
        add     r8, rbp
        xor     ecx, ecx
        shr     rbx
        xor     edx, edx
.L31:
        movdqu  xmm0, XMMWORD PTR [r9+rcx]
        movdqu  xmm2, XMMWORD PTR [r8+rcx]
        add     rdx, 1
        movups  XMMWORD PTR [r9+rcx], xmm2
        movups  XMMWORD PTR [r8+rcx], xmm0
        sub     rcx, 16
        cmp     rdx, rbx
        jne     .L31
        mov     rdx, rsi
        and     rdx, -2
        mov     rcx, rdx
        neg     rcx
        sal     rcx, 3
        cmp     rsi, rdx
        je      .L34
        sub     rcx, 8
        lea     rdx, [r10+rcx]
        add     rcx, r11
        mov     r8, QWORD PTR [rdx]
        mov     r9, QWORD PTR [rcx]
        mov     QWORD PTR [rdx], r9
        mov     QWORD PTR [rcx], r8
.L34:
        neg     rsi
        lea     rbp, [r10+rsi*8]
.L29:
        cqo
        idiv    rdi
        mov     rsi, rdx
        test    rdx, rdx
        je      .L1
        mov     rax, rdi
        jmp     .L15
.L14:
        movdqu  xmm0, XMMWORD PTR [rbp+0]
        shufpd  xmm0, xmm0, 1
        movups  XMMWORD PTR [rbp+0], xmm0
.L1:
        pop     rbx
        pop     rbp
        pop     r12
        ret
.L38:
        mov     rdx, -8
        xor     ecx, ecx
.L30:
        mov     r8, QWORD PTR [r10+rdx]
        mov     r9, QWORD PTR [r11+rdx]
        add     rcx, 1
        mov     QWORD PTR [r10+rdx], r9
        mov     QWORD PTR [r11+rdx], r8
        sub     rdx, 8
        cmp     rsi, rcx
        jne     .L30
        jmp     .L34
.L36:
        xor     ecx, ecx
.L20:
        mov     r8, QWORD PTR [rbp+0+rcx*8]
        mov     r9, QWORD PTR [rdx+rcx*8]
        mov     QWORD PTR [rbp+0+rcx*8], r9
        mov     QWORD PTR [rdx+rcx*8], r8
        add     rcx, 1
        cmp     rdi, rcx
        jne     .L20
        jmp     .L24
.L37:
        mov     rbp, r10
        jmp     .L29
.L75:
        mov     rcx, rax
        sub     rcx, rbp
        sar     rcx, 3
.L2:
        cmp     rcx, 2
        je      .L8
        cmp     rcx, 3
        je      .L9
        cmp     rcx, 1
        je      .L10
.L11:
        mov     rbp, rax
        xor     eax, eax
        jmp     .L35
.L9:
        cmp     rsi, QWORD PTR [rbp+0]
        je      .L3
        add     rbp, 8
.L8:
        cmp     rsi, QWORD PTR [rbp+0]
        je      .L3
        add     rbp, 8
.L10:
        cmp     rsi, QWORD PTR [rbp+0]
        jne     .L11
        jmp     .L3
.L72:
        add     rbp, 8
        jmp     .L3
.L73:
        add     rbp, 16
        jmp     .L3
.L74:
        add     rbp, 24
        jmp     .L3
.L77:
        sal     rax, 3
        lea     rsi, [rbp+8]
        mov     r12, QWORD PTR [rbp+0]
        lea     rbx, [rbp+0+rax]
        cmp     rbx, rsi
        je      .L18
        lea     rdx, [rax-8]
        mov     rdi, rbp
        call    memmove
.L18:
        mov     QWORD PTR [rbx-8], r12
        jmp     .L1
.L79:
        lea     rax, [r11-8]
        mov     rbx, QWORD PTR [r11-8]
        cmp     rbp, rax
        je      .L28
        sub     rax, rbp
        mov     rdi, r11
        mov     rsi, rbp
        mov     rdx, rax
        sub     rdi, rax
        call    memmove
.L28:
        mov     QWORD PTR [rbp+0], rbx
        jmp     .L1
```

https://godbolt.org/z/P83YT37f8

So, the Most important question is: **Does it mean that the STL version is slower? If so, by what magnitude?**

And another question would be: **Why is the assembly so bloated with -O3?**

---

So, I've done some benchmarking:

```
#include <cstddef>

struct Shape
{
    static size_t count;
    size_t id = count++;
};

size_t Shape::count = 0;

#include <vector>

struct Window
{
    std::vector<Shape*> shapes;

    void move_to_top_manual(Shape& s);
    void move_to_top(Shape& s);

};

void Window::move_to_top_manual(Shape& s)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < shapes.size(); ++i)
        if (&s == shapes[i])
        {
            for (++i; i < shapes.size(); ++i)
                shapes[i - 1] = shapes[i];
            shapes[shapes.size() - 1] = &s;
            return;
        }
}

#include <algorithm>

void Window::move_to_top(Shape& s)
{
    auto iterShape = std::find(shapes.begin(), shapes.end(), &s);
    std::rotate(iterShape, std::next(iterShape), shapes.end());
}

#include <chrono>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    size_t indx = argc < 2 ? 0 : std::stoll(argv[1]);

    std::vector<Shape> shapes{size_t(5000000)};

    Window window{};
    window.shapes.reserve(shapes.size());
    for(auto &s : shapes)
        window.shapes.push_back(std::addressof(s));

    Window windowsManual = window;

    std::chrono::nanoseconds stlDuration{},
            manualDuration{};
    {
        Shape &moveToTop = *window.shapes[indx];

        auto timePointBegin = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();
        window.move_to_top(moveToTop);
        auto timePointEnd = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();

        stlDuration = timePointEnd - timePointBegin;

        std::cout << "STL nanosec: " << stlDuration.count() << std::endl;
        if (&moveToTop != window.shapes.back())
            return -1;
    }

    {
        Shape &moveToTop = *windowsManual.shapes[indx];

        auto timePointBegin = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();
        windowsManual.move_to_top_manual(moveToTop);
        auto timePointEnd = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();

        manualDuration = timePointEnd - timePointBegin;

        std::cout << "Manual nanosec: " << manualDuration.count() << std::endl;
        if (&moveToTop != windowsManual.shapes.back())
            return -1;
    }

    std::cout << "STL/Manual = " << double(stlDuration.count()) / manualDuration.count();
    return 0;
}
```

On average with MSVC the STL version is 1.5-2.0 times slower than Manual.

```
STL nanosec: 19559200
Manual nanosec: 10636300
STL/Manual = 1.83891

STL nanosec: 20507700
Manual nanosec: 11418600
STL/Manual = 1.79599

Manual nanosec: 11685300
STL/Manual = 1.70025
```

So, **it is** slower with MSVC.

With MinGW64 It is roughly the same:

```
STL nanosec: 9069300
Manual nanosec: 7860500
STL/Manual = 1.15378

STL nanosec: 8865300
Manual nanosec: 11290500
STL/Manual = 0.7852

STL nanosec: 10713700
Manual nanosec: 8235200
STL/Manual = 1.30096
```

Running this on [godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/YYGq8Wve9) produces unexpected results:

```
STL nanosec: 3551159
Manual nanosec: 30056271
STL/Manual = 0.11815
```

Comment: More code doesn't automatically mean slower. There could be loop unrolling, there could be checking for and handling of special corner cases which won't affect 99% of cases, etc. The only way to check efficiency is to measure, and measure perhaps thousands of times to get an average.

Comment: "bloated" is a very subjective term, could you elaborate on what you mean? Is it just code length?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I totally agree that actual performance is measured by benchmarking, not by the amount of asm instructions. However, I just didn't expect that much of a difference

Comment: @ShadowMitia the length

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I've added some simple benchmarking

Answer (score 3):

> Does it mean that the STL version is slower?

No, different assembly doesn't necessarily mean slower. The number of assembly instructions is not a reliable metric of quality.

> If so, by what magnitude?

It depends. You can find out by measuring the speed. Benchmarking is also difficult, although not quite as difficult as guessing efficiency based on assembly.

Comment: There was nothing about duplicates, so given these are shapes, I assume they are unique.

Comment: "One significant difference is that if there are duplicates, then the first version rotates all to the end" - I don't think it does, because the outer loop counter is modified by the inner loop.

Comment: @SebastianRedl Yeah, I noticed that part of my answer was wrong a few moments ago. I hadn't noticed the early return in the first program (and indeed the shared accumulator).

Comment: I've updated the question with benchmarking. STL version appears to be 1.5-2.0 times slower.